# Applying Names / Values to HTML List from Javascript Array of Objects

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, object

I have a Javascript array of objects populating an HTML list.

```
<html>
<head>
  <script src="jquery-2.1.4.min.js"></script>
  <script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
    // js array of objects
    var location = [{
         City: "Akron",
         State: "Ohio",
         Temperature_1: 50,
         Temperature_2: 65
     }, {
         City: "Charlotte",
         State: "North Carolina",
         Temperature_1: 80,
         Temperature_2: 90
     }];

     // populate webpage with locations and temperatures
     $.each(location, function(key, val) {
       var $locationList = $("<li>" + "<div class='group'>" + val.City + "<div class='both_temperatures '>" + "<div class='temperature'>" + val.Temperature_1 + "</div>" + "<div class='temperature'>" + val.Temperature_2 + "</div></div><div class='state'>" + val.State + "</div></li>");
            $("#locationList").append($locationList);
     });
   });
   </script>
 </head>
 <body>
   <ul id="locationList"></ul>
 </body>
</html>
```

I'm able to get the following output:

```
<ul id="locationList">
  <li>
    <div class="group">Akron
      <div class="both_temperatures">
        <div class="temperature">50</div>
        <div class="temperature">65</div>
      </div>
      <div class="state">Ohio</div>
    </div>
  </li>
  <li>
    <div class="group">Charlotte
      <div class="both_temperatures">
        <div class="temperature">80</div>
        <div class="temperature">90</div>
      </div>
      <div class="state">North Carolina</div>
    </div>
  </li>
</ul>
```

How do I assign names within the "class" divs and values within the "temperature" divs?

Here is my desired output:

```
<ul id="locationList">
  <li>
    <div class="group" name="Akron">Akron
      <div class="both_temperatures">
        <div class="temperature" value="50">50</div>
        <div class="temperature" value="65">65</div>
      </div>
      <div class="state" name="Ohio">Ohio</div>
    </div>
  </li>
  <li>
    <div class="group" name="Charlotte">Charlotte
      <div class="both_temperatures">
        <div class="temperature" value="80">80</div>
        <div class="temperature" value="90">90</div>
      </div>
      <div class="state" name="North Carolina">North Carolina</div>
    </div>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try this

```
var $locationList = $("<li>" + "<div class='group' name='"+val.City+"'>" + val.City + "<div class='both_temperatures '>" + "<div class='temperature' value='"+val.Temperature_1+"'>" + val.Temperature_1 + "</div>" + "<div class='temperature' value='"+val.Temperature_2+"'>" + val.Temperature_2 + "</div></div><div class='state' name='"+val.State+"'>" + val.State + "</div></li>");
```

Comment: Perfect! Thanks, Ozgur!

Comment: @Matthew happy coding!